# puppet 3.2.4: stack level too deep

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I am working on a refactoring project for a large repository of custom puppet modules.  This includes an upgrade from puppet 2.x to 3.2.4.  When I finally hit critical mass and started testing some of the changes, I quickly ran into the following error:

```
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/base/lib/facter/elversion.rb
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/base/lib/facter/site.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/elversion.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/site.rb
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: stack level too deep at /etc/puppet/manifests/nodes.pp:9 on node puppet
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

After looking through various puppet bug reports, I decided to try simplifying the problem.  I narrowed the issue down to two classes, defined as such:

```
class base::includes { }
```

and

```
class prod_secure::base::includes inherits base::includes { }
```

A node that includes nothing but prod_secure::base::includes produces the error output listed above.  The only possibly related warning that I see in `puppet-lint` is:

```
WARNING: class inherits across module namespaces on line 1
```

...but that's just a warning, and shouldn't crash puppet on an agent run, I wouldn't think.   Any ideas?  Is it possible that the namespacing scheme that I have set up unsupported by puppet?

**UPDATE**

I decided to take the testing a step further, and change the name of the inheriting class.  The new definition is:

```
class prod_secure::base2::includes2 inherits base::includes { }
```

The result is the same... `stack level too deep`.  It looks to me like this issue has nothing to do with namespacing.

**UPDATE 2**

During the previous round of debugging I missed one salient detail:

```
Wed Sep 11 11:25:09 -0400 2013 Puppet (info): Caching node for puppet
Wed Sep 11 11:25:09 -0400 2013 Puppet (debug): importing '/etc/puppet/manifests/nodes.pp' in environment production
Wed Sep 11 11:25:09 -0400 2013 Puppet (debug): importing '/etc/puppet/manifests/config_file.pp' in environment production
Wed Sep 11 11:25:10 -0400 2013 Puppet (debug): importing '/etc/puppet/modules/prod_secure/manifests/base2/includes2.pp' in environment production
Wed Sep 11 11:25:10 -0400 2013 Puppet (debug): Automatically imported prod_secure::base2::includes2 from prod_secure/base2/includes2 into production
Wed Sep 11 11:25:10 -0400 2013 Puppet (debug): importing '/etc/puppet/modules/prod_secure/manifests/base/includes.pp' in environment production
Wed Sep 11 11:25:10 -0400 2013 Puppet (debug): Automatically imported prod_secure::base::includes from prod_secure/base/includes into production
Wed Sep 11 11:25:10 -0400 2013 Puppet (err): stack level too deep at /etc/puppet/manifests/nodes.pp:9 on node puppet
Wrapped exception:
stack level too deep
```

I can't say I'm sure why, but it was still trying to load prod_secure::base::includes, and that was the offending entry.  After removing that file entirely, the test passed.  I'm back to the namespacing theory...

Comment: Do you have a module that tries to load `'modulename/*.pp'` manually, as a work for some autoloader problems way back in Puppet 0.25.x? I've seen this cause problems with modern versions of Puppet.

Comment: Just checked and...no.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try puppet 3.2.3.

3.2.2 had [#21376](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/21376) similiar  problem, but it was fixed in 3.2.3, it might be regression